# Unknown member 'SortDescriptions' on element 'CollectionViewSource'

Tags: winrt-xaml, collectionviewsource

This is a real newbie question. I feel dumb that I have not figured it out yet.  I am trying to add a sort to my CollectionViewSource in my Win 8 App.

```
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        x:Key="cvs"
        Source="{Binding Items}">

        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="PubDate" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

    </CollectionViewSource>
```

I have the following namespaces declared:
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"

But I get the error "Unknown member 'SortDescriptions' on element 'CollectionViewSource'" when I try to build. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [CollecitonViewSource in WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) does not have SortDescription. You may have to order the Items instead.

This link might help as well.

[A WinRT CollectionView class with Filtering and Sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So?msg=4513261#xx4513261xx)